# Reload sound not playing at correct time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in this reload script The gun reloads and THEN plays the reload sound. The thing is that the reload should play first. Another problem is i would like to get rid of the work around I did to make the reload key work. They reason I made the Ammo = 0 when I press reload is because before i added that in the ammo wouldn't reset back to 8. I just don't really understand why when i reload the sound doesn't play until after the delay goes through. Thank you for taking the time to read this post.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Reload : MonoBehaviour
{
    //amount of bullets in the mag
    public static int Ammo;
    private float timer = 0.0f;
    public float reloadTime = 3.0f;
    //calls upon a command in a diffrent script that cancels the ablity to shoot
    public PauseManager reload;
    //plays the audio
    public AudioSource reloadfx;


    Text text;


    void Awake ()
    {
        reloadfx = GetComponent <AudioSource> ();
        text = GetComponent <Text> ();
        Ammo = 8;
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        //I used this line as a underhanded way of allowing the Reload key to reload the pistol.\
        //This is also my work around.
        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Reload") && Ammo < 8) 
        {
            Ammo = 0;
        }
        //IF Ammo is 0 or I press the reload and i am not full of ammo then reload
        if (Ammo == 0 || Input.GetButtonDown ("Reload") && Ammo < 8) 
        {
            //plays the sound
            reloadfx.Play ();
            ReloadAction ();
        }
        else 
        {
            //enable the ablity to shoot
            reload.shoot = true;
        }
        //display the ammunition
        text.text = Ammo + "/8";
    }

    public void ReloadAction()
    {
        //for as long as the timer is smaller then the reload time
        if (timer < reloadTime) 
        {
            //disable the abillity to shoot
            reload.shoot = false;
            //count the time
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
        } 
        else 
        {
            //after the reload reset the timer and ammo count
            Ammo = 8;
            timer = 0.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the sound play at all?

Comment: Welcome to the site - I've added an answer, feel free to ask me any questions about it if you find anything unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate reason for this happening is because `reloadfx.Play ();` is being called for every frame that your reloading is occurring. That means it's getting restarted over and over, until finally your reload finishes and it can play in its entirety.

However, the root cause of this is how you've structured the conditions around your reloading logic. My recommendation is to just have a flag that actually indicates your gun is reloading, rather than indirectly signalling it through `Ammo == 0`. When `Input.GetButtonDown ("Reload")` occurs and the conditions are correct for reloading, play the reload sound and set the flag to true. Then, set the flag to false when reloading has completed.

There are a number of ways you can change this, but here's what I feel is a pretty simple rewrite of your approach:

```
private bool isReloading = false;

void Update ()
{
    if (!isReloading)
    {
        // When ammo has depleted or player forces a reload
        if (Ammo == 0 || (Input.GetButtonDown ("Reload") && Ammo < 8))
        {
            // Play sound once, signal reloading to begin, and disable shooting
            reloadfx.Play ();
            isReloading = true;
            reload.shoot = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // isReloading will be the opposite of whether the reload is finished
        isReloading = !ReloadAction();
        if (!isReloading)
        {
            // Once reloading is done, enable shooting
            reload.shoot = true;
        }
    }
    text.text = Ammo + "/8";
}

// Performs reload action, then returns whether reloading is complete
public bool ReloadAction()
{
    //for as long as the timer is smaller then the reload time
    if (timer < reloadTime) 
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        //after the reload reset the timer and ammo count
        Ammo = 8;
        timer = 0.0f;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much. The sound plays perfectly and now when i press the reload key it actually reloads!